# Strange rendering Ubuntu 18.04 GeForce GTX 960

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, fonts, antialiasing, subpixel-rendering

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 and since that some programs render strange. I did not have the problem with Ubuntu 16.04. The terminal looks fine. But for example, the text and icons in Teams and Chrome look blurry.

[image: Blurry chrome]

[image: Blurry teams]

I tried various anti-aliasing settings using Tweaks Tool (subpixel, grayscale and None) with different scaling factor. But although it changes the blurriness, I cannot get it perfectly clear. Is there a way to automatically get the right setting.

I also tried to enable and disable FXAA in Nvidia settings. I have NVIDIA 460.80 driver. But still it's slightly blurry.

Comment: Is this a laptop or desktop? What screen are you using?

Comment: It's a desktop PC, I use 2 screens, Samsung S27D390H PLS 27 inch LED HDMI and LG 32MP58HQ-P: 32 Inch Class Full HD IPS LED Monitor